# How to reboot a azure vm from powershell script and continue the remaining steps

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have an azure VM . Am writing a powershell script which executes two .bat files after that it has to reboot the azure VM after that it has to continue to execute remaining .bat files.

Here's the below script

Step1:`set-location -path C:/temp`

Step2:`start-process cmd.exe /c "abc.bat" -wait`

Step3:`start-process cmd.exe /c "123.bat" -wait`

Step4:`restart-computer -Force`

Step5:`start-process cmd.exe /c "prod.bat" -wait`

Step6:`start-process cmd.exe /c "dev.bat" -wait`

Am executing this script remotely by giving below command

```
PS C:\> Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '/Users/username/sample.ps1'
```

After running the above command its executing fine up to "step 4" .After that its not continuing with the remaining steps

Can you please help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that I can think of and detailing them below :

### Approach 1 :

Using the registry key **RUNONCE** - which can be used to specify commands that the system will execute one time and then delete.

More information available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys).

There will be slight modification in when running it remotely.

When you use the `Invoke-AzVMRunCommand` , the initial command will have to copy the 2 script files to a temporary location in the remote VM and kick start the first script (this contains steps 1-3)

And before step 4 - you will create a registry key entry under RUNONCE :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

set-location HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
new-itemproperty . MyKey -propertytype String -value "Powershell c:\temp\script2.ps1"
```

Or Alternatively you can directly add the .bat files under the RunOnce keys.

The file gets under RUNONCE keys gets executed after login and gets deleted after the execution.

### Approach 2 :

You could refer to the below article which creates workflow and also creates **ScheduledTask** to resume the suspended workflow.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powershell-workflows-restarting-the-computer/#automatic-restart-of-workflow

```
workflow test-restart {

 #STEPS 1-3

 Restart-Computer -Wait

 #STEPS 5 - 6
}
```

For scheduling :

```
$act = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $pstart -Argument $actionscript
$trig = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn
```

**NOTE :**
It is not mandatory to use workflows like in the example. You can write your own logic to resume at the point where you had left once it has been re-triggered - by persisting the step data.

The **key** to this approach is to create a scheduled task which gets triggered to continue the script automatically after a restart.

Even in this case, it may be necessary to copy the scripts locally to the machine.

Comment: Thanks sathya  Do you mean that i have to create separate script called  c:\temp\script2.ps1 with steps 5 to 6 and place in the initial script .So my script finally looks like this ?      Step1:set-location -path C:/temp

Step2:start-process cmd.exe /c "abc.bat" -wait

Step3:start-process cmd.exe /c "123.bat" -wait

step4:set-location HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce
new-itemproperty . MyKey -propertytype String -value "Powershell c:\temp\script2.ps1" .Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: Hi sathya , Do i need to add command "restart-computer" after step 4

Comment: Yeah, once you set the registry key you can initiate the restart-computer command

Comment: @nikhileshwary - did the above steps work for you ? Also, please consider accepting the answer as solution if it had helped.

Comment: Hi Sathya , Its not working . My doubt is this script path "Powershell c:\temp\script2.ps1" exists in local computer .May be this path is in local computer not in VM is that reason its not working ?

Comment: did you copy the script2 to the destination VM ?

Comment: No , both the scripts are in my local computer . How to copy that script to the destination VM .Can you please tell me

Comment: https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/07/copy-files-to-azure-vm-using-powershell-remoting/